# Why do the derivations of $\ln(\frac{a}{b})$ and $\ln(a) - \ln(b)$ yield different results

Tags: analysis, derivatives, logarithms

So I was doing some exercises and I noticed that for one example which was of the form $$\ln( \frac{a}{b} )$$ (with a and b being some term with x), that I was getting a different result for taking the derivation when using the logarithmic rule $$\ln( \frac{a}{b} ) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$$ before deriving  versus applying chain and quotient rules right away.

I tried this with some other examples of that form too and I always ended up getting different results, but I have no idea what would cause this to happen.

One of the examples I tried would be $$\ln( \frac{4+x}{4-x} )$$ which yields $$\frac{-8+8x}{(4+x)^3}$$ when applying chain and quotient rules right away and
$$\frac{8}{16-x^2}$$ when using $$\ln( \frac{a}{b} ) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$$ before deriving.

Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you come up with $\frac{-8+8x}{(4+x)^3}$?

Comment: They never should. The fact that the two derivatives differ tells you that an error was made somewhere.

Comment: @pendermath $$ln(\frac{4+x}{4-x})' = \frac{4-x}{4+x} * \frac{-(4+x) - (4-x)}{(4+x)^2} = \frac{-8 + 8*x}{(4+x)^3}$$ is what I did

Comment: My suspicion is you applied the chain rule wrong and calculated $$(\frac{4+x}{4-x})^{-1}[\frac{4-x}{4+x}]'$$ instead of $$(\frac{4+x}{4-x})^{-1}[\frac{4+x}{4-x}]'$$ which is the right way of applying the chain rule.

Comment: See my answer below. Also, look at @FlorisClaassens remark. It seems you reversed the second factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you differentiate $\log\left(\frac{4+x}{4-x}\right)$ directly, what you get is$$\frac{\left(\frac{4+x}{4-x}\right)'}{\frac{4+x}{4-x}}=\frac{\frac{4-x+4-x}{(4-x)^2}}{\frac{4+x}{4-x}}=\frac8{(4-x)(4+x)}.\tag1$$And if you differentiate $\log(4+x)-\log(4-x)$, what you get is$$\frac1{4+x}+\frac1{4-x},$$which is equal to $(1)$.

Comment: I just applied the chain rule wrong, really stupid mistake. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative is $\frac{8}{16-x^2}$ no matter how you solve it.

Directly (as a quotient): $$\frac{\frac{1}{(4-x)^2}}{\frac{4+x}{4-x}}(4-x+4+x) = \frac{8}{16-x^2}$$

Using the log rule ($\log(4+x) - \log(4-x)$): $$\frac{1}{4+x} + \frac{1}{4-x} = \frac{8}{16-x^2}$$